# Unable to access stored packages from Google artifact registry on Java springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I've been trying to manage my java jar files on Google cloud artifact registry using maven build. I was successful on uploading the jar file to the artifact registry. And when I'm trying to add that jar file in my another project, the maven build is successful, but I'm unable to use that package!!

What could be the possible reason?

PS: I've already included this in my pom.xml

```
<project>
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>artifact-registry</id>
      <url>{url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
      <id>artifact-registry</id>
      <url>{url}</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>artifact-registry</id>
      <url>{url}</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
</project>
```

I’ve following these documentations

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/store-java

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java

Comment: Suppose your application depends on this jar file being uploaded to GCP. In that case, you need to add a dependency to that jar file in your application pom file, just like any other dependency your application may use.

Comment: Yes, I’ve done it, but it’s still not working, that jar from GCP is getting downloaded, but I’m unable to import it!!

Comment: Could you show how you're adding those as dependency to your project?

Comment: I'm including it like this

<dependency>
   <groupId>{groupdId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

Comment: FYI : I'm able to fetch the jar from the GCP artifact registry, but I'm not sure, why isn't getting loaded in the location I wanted it to be!
I can even see that jar in the External libraries tab!

Comment: What is meant by "...I'm not sure, why isn't getting loaded in the location..."?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error, the main error on loading the dependency because of the jar structure of springboot application.

I followed the following article: [https://medium.com/publicis-sapient-france/import-spring-boot-application-as-a-maven-dependency-a25e03e5c3a#:~:text=The%20solution%20that%20we%20found,be%20imported%20from%20other%20projects.&text=Now%2C%20we%20got%20two%20JARs,%2Dapp%2Dto%2Dimport](https://medium.com/publicis-sapient-france/import-spring-boot-application-as-a-maven-dependency-a25e03e5c3a#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20that%20we%20found,be%20imported%20from%20other%20projects.&text=Now%2C%20we%20got%20two%20JARs,%2Dapp%2Dto%2Dimport).